# ng new didn't work, showing blank terminal screen

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I want to create my first Angular project. I have a problem at the beginning, because when i go to the project folder and type:

```
ng new my-first-project
```

Nothing happens. I only see blank terminal:

[image]

My:

```
npm -v: 6.4.1
node -v: 10.11.0
ng -v: Mg++ version:
  Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.)
```

I tried:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli 
npm cache clean 
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

but nothing has changed. I also tried the same with node 8.x.x however, the effect was the same.

I working on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and my default system language is different than English.

Comment: Have you tried using another shell? Like Cmder?

Comment: Apparently you've got something called "Mg++" installed which is calls its binary `ng`. You can try to call the Angular `ng` directly from its default instalaltion position `~/.node/bin/ng`.

Comment: instead "ng new my-first-project" i had to type "/home/jakub/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng new my-first-app". Problem solved, thank you!

Comment: I had a similar experience the way I resolved the issue was using nvm to switch my node to the previous version of 17.1.0 it turned out that I at some point had to downgrade my node version to 14.4, so after running nvm use 17.1.0 my ng commands started working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this**

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in your terminal

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue trying Sai Lao's answer gave me an error because there were global configuration related to npm as I was using nvm .
I had to uninstall and re-install angular cli again using the following commands

```
sudo apt remove ng-common
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ng
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution. I Solve it installing last version node with nvm.

nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
npm install -g @angular/cli